Chat scrolls in the middle or up when I send a message
I have an issue to my current chat ui , each time a user sends a booking request or a message the chat ui automatically scrolls up or middle of chat, how I can block the view of the user at the bottom of the chat after sending a message? The app is made in flutter, I created this function scrollToBottom, but there is no package? or what should I add
void sendMessage() {
    final messageText = messageController.text.trim();
    if (messageText.isEmpty) return;
    
    messageController.clear();
    
    // Send message in background
    Future(() async {
      try {
        final chatRoomId = getChatRoomId();
        final messageDoc = messageColl
            .doc(chatRoomId)
            .collection("chats")
            .doc();

        await messageDoc.set({
          'sender': currentUserId,
          'time': DateTime.now(),
          'type': 'text',
          'message': messageText,
          'unread': true,
        });

        // Update chat room in background
        messageColl.doc(chatRoomId).set({
          "users": [currentUserId, widget.serviceProviderId],
          "chatRoomId": chatRoomId,
          "lastMessage": messageText,
          "lastMessageTime": DateTime.now(),
        });

        // Scroll to bottom after sending message
        _scrollToBottom();

      } catch (e) {
        print('Error sending message: $e');
      }
    });
  }
void _scrollToBottom() {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        );
      });
    }
  }

  // Add this method to properly handle scroll position
  void _maintainScrollPosition(VoidCallback callback) {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      final currentPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      callback();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
          _scrollController.jumpTo(currentPosition);
        }
      });
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  // Add this method to handle keyboard visibility
  void _handleKeyboardVisibility() {
    if (mounted) {
      final bottomInset = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
      if (bottomInset > 0 && _scrollController.hasClients) {
        // Delay the scroll to ensure the keyboard is fully shown
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
          _scrollToBottom();
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Widget buildMessageItem(Map<String, dynamic> messageData) {
    bool isMe = messageData['sender'] == currentUserId;
    
    if (messageData['type'] == 'booking_request') {
      bool isTimeUpdated = messageData['isTimeUpdated'] == true;
      bool needsResponse = messageData['needsResponse'] == true;
      bool isOriginalSender = messageData['sender'] == currentUserId;
      String status = messageData['status'] ?? 'pending';
      
      return Column(
        children: [
          BookingCard(bookingData: messageData),
          
          // Show accept/decline buttons only when status is pending AND time is updated AND needs response
          if (isTimeUpdated && 
              needsResponse && 
              isOriginalSender && 
              status == 'pending')
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () => handleRescheduleResponse(messageData['docId'], true),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                      label: const Text(
                        'Accept Time',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () => handleRescheduleResponse(messageData['docId'], false),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                      label: const Text(
                        'Decline Time',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          
          // Show provider buttons only if not updated and is service provider
          if (!isTimeUpdated && 
              messageData['serviceProviderId'] == currentUserId && 
              status == 'pending')
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () => handleRescheduleResponse(messageData['docId'], true),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                      label: const Text(
                        'Accept',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () => showRescheduleDialog(messageData['docId']),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.schedule, color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                      label: const Text(
                        'Reschedule',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () => handleRescheduleResponse(messageData['docId'], false),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                      label: const Text(
                        'Decline',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return buildTextMessage(messageData, isMe);
    }
  }

